# How to create a list of FULL Nodes without titles (Views)

Tags: views, 6

I would like to create a list of FULL nodes with comments but no titles (with the module Views) is that possible?

Currently I have already a list which shows the FULL node with comments. But also the title which is even an URL.

Can someone explain me how I can do this with Views? If it isn't possible, is it then possible to have the title listed as plain text instead of an URL (duplicated content etc.)?

Using Drupal 6.x

Thanks in advance!

Ps: Just thinking, or should this be done with theming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the **full node** view and get rid of the title I would suggest you doing this with CSS `display:none`.
The method of @iStryker is good but it will just show a list of fields and you'll have to theme them in order to recreate the node view.

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about something like this. Only when you 'hide' content wouldn't that be against the rules of search-engines like Google? Anyway when I'm back home and have some spare time I will try to figure out which solution fits me the best.

Comment: IMHO I think there's no problem because it's very little content, it's not like you're putting a bunch of URL in a hidden section of the footer, also these are internals links so google won't consider your "spamming" your own site ;)

Comment: I customized the node theme for this content type. I removed the title field. So only the body and comments are getting printed. So at the end the theming idea was the solution. To be honest, should have figured that out of myself. I guess I was too much focused on Views.

Answer (score 1):

To create a view of just comments,  Remove the `Node:Title` field (and all other fields), and add `Comment: Body`

To have the node title not a link, uncheck 'Link this field to its node'[image: View Example of Link this field to its node]

Comment: Thanks, tonight I will figure out what advice fits me the best :)

Answer (score 0):

exclude_node_title is a module for excluding many types of node and is available here for Drupal 6 and Drupal 7:

http://drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title

With this module, a checkbox is available for you to uncheck displaying the title.